# Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-not-exists

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Click(
    in  ipaddress varchar(45))
BEGIN
    DECLARE ex int;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ex FROM clickactivity WHERE IP = ipaddress;
IF ex = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO clickactivity (IP, Clicks) VALUES(ipaddress, 0);
END IF;   
    UPDATE clickactivity SET Clicks = Clicks + 1;
END
```

It complains about line 4 like so:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things wrong

First, use `DELIMITER $$` so semicolons are interpreted inside the stored procedure and not the command line. After defining the stored procedure, switch the delimiter back to semicolon (`;`).

Next, `UPDATE clickactivity SET Clicks = Clicks + 1;` will update every row and you don't want that.

## SUGGESTION #1

Add `WHERE IP = ipaddress;` to the `UPDATE clickactivity`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Click(in ipaddress varchar(45))
BEGIN
    DECLARE ex int;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ex FROM clickactivity WHERE IP = ipaddress;
    IF ex = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO clickactivity (IP, Clicks) VALUES (ipaddress, 0);
    END IF;   
    UPDATE clickactivity SET Clicks = Clicks + 1 WHERE IP = ipaddress;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

## SUGGESTION #2

Why do two or three queries to register a single click ?

Change the code to do the query so that it INSERTs and UPDATEs at the same time

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Click(in ipaddress varchar(45))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO clickactivity (IP, Clicks) VALUES (ipaddress, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Clicks = Clicks + 1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

In that event, you don't need a stored procedure. Just do the INSERT

```
INSERT INTO clickactivity (IP, Clicks) VALUES (ipaddress, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Clicks = Clicks + 1;
```

Of course, doing this works if `ipaddress` is the `PRIMARY KEY` or is a `UNIQUE KEY` in `clickactivity`.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: My upvote for a more complete answer, although I still prefer the poor version of `$$` :-) I would also point the potential problem of contention that is storing a counter in a MySQL table.

Comment: @jynus That's another can of worms I did want to open here. I did write a post about that last year (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49360/mysql-for-analytics-and-updating-same-row/49362#49362)

Comment: yeah the suggestion  #1 is really a thing I wanted to add WHERE IP = ipaddress

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is ok, you just need to temporarily change the end of statement delimiter, like this:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE Click(
    ->     in  ipaddress varchar(45))
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE ex int;
    ->     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ex FROM clickactivity WHERE IP = ipaddress;
    -> IF ex = 0 THEN
    ->     INSERT INTO clickactivity (IP, Clicks) VALUES(ipaddress, 0);
    -> END IF;   
    ->     UPDATE clickactivity SET Clicks = Clicks + 1;
    -> END //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
```

If not, the MySQL command line (or other clients) will treat the first `;` as the end of the procedure declaration. In other words, you need to change the delimiter in order to "insert" the semicolon character.

Comment: nice will give that a try

Comment: I wouldn't think it's the delimeter causing these random errors it works now.

Comment: Not having a new delimiter caused it. The error message says it happened on line 4. That's the first semicolon in the stored proc code. All statements prior to the first semicolon `CREATE PROCEDURE Click(in  ipaddress varchar(45)) BEGIN DECLARE ex int` was being considered a single MySQL command. Adding `DELIMITER \\` changed everything in terms of context.